# HTML5: How to place two images side by side followed by a figcaption beneath?

Tags: css, html

I like to use the following, clean markup:

```
<figure>
    <img src="foo.png" alt=""/>
    <img src="bar.png" alt=""/>
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit maecenas venenatis lectus nec ligula faucibus tincidunt</figcaption>
</figure>
```

1. I like to present the two pictures side by side.
2. The figcaption should be not wider than the two pictures side by side.
3. I do not want to use any image specific width value in the CSS or HTML.

I tried to solve the problem with the following CSS, which works fine in Firefox:

```
figure { display: table; }
figcaption { 
display: table-caption; 
caption-side: bottom ;
}
img { display: table-cell; }
```

I tested that CSS in Chrome (macOS) and Safari (iOS). It does not work.

I looked at http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell without success.

Is there any solution which works on most plattforms/browsers?

There is another extra target, I will not conceal:
When the viewport gets smaller than the width of the two pictures side by side, than the presentation should switch from side by side to one top of the other.

But first: I would happy if there's a solution for the main target.

Thanks. And sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Try looking into flexbox. I personally haven't mastered it but it is a feature whose purpose is to assist in making the layout work across more platforms.

Comment: Try replacing table-cell with inline-table and it should work. I tried it in Firefox, Chrome and Safari for mac and it worked for me.

Comment: @Simrandeep Singh
Works fine. Even in iOS Safari. Thanks a lot. I will add the solution to the first message.

Comment: Because I couldn't mark your comment, Simrandeep, as the solution (only answers can marked in that way), I posted an answer myself. Is that the correct way in this forum?

Comment: I will add the answer. You can remove yours.

Comment: Thanks. Because I mentioned http://caniuse.com as a source for the compatibility of specific CSS properties/values: it does not contain information, that { display: table-cell; } will not work in iOS Safari or Chrome. Does anyone know another source for the compatibility of all the table values of the property display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for this issue.

You can use

```
img { display: inline-table; }
```

instead of

```
img { display: table-cell; }
```